# Is there a text editor that auto reloads the page in the browser as I type?

Tags: css, browsers, text-editor

I'm new to web design and working on some complex CSS and currently I'm working with the dev tools in FireFox and tweaking the CSS there then switching to Sublime Text to retype the altered CSS. Is there an easier way? Something that updates the page in the browser as I type so I can instantly see the effect? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (VSCode) with the [Live Server extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer). It works best with Google Chrome. VSCode is a free download from Microsoft.

Since you're working with CSS, I would also recommend the [IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion).

You could also try something like [codepen.io](https://codepen.io) or [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io). They both allow you to edit HTML & CSS content and see the changes live in the browser.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll check it out.